# Is there a word for "clever fool?"

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who despite being very clever in one field, e.g. math or physics, behaves very unwisely or impractical in real life?
I know some people who are very well educated and can solve difficult scientific problems, but they seem to belong to some different society. They can easily be cheated by any fraud, they are often absentminded so they lose their belonging all the time etc.
Do you have a word for this kind of people?

Comment: "Absentminded professor" (not one word) and "nerd" (implies social awkwardness, not foolishness) sprang to mind, but neither is a perfect fit.

Comment: The time has come to borrow the German *Fachidiot*.

Comment: Isn't that a _Nerd_ ?

Comment: There was of course [James I & VI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisest_fool_in_Christendom) who was said to be "the wisest fool in Christendom, meaning him wise in small things, but a fool in weighty affairs"

Comment: @RegDwight: Oh, thanks, when I start to learn German it will be great to know this word from the very beginning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've heard people like that described as *[book smart](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=book%20smart)*. It is sometimes used as the opposite of *street-smart*.

> Being able to succeed scholastically, and not necessarily in the real world.

*Urban Dictionary*

Comment: ++ Probably the most suitable term, along with *naive*.

Comment: There are so many interesting versions and it is a pity that I can chose only one.

Answer (score 12):

An [idiot savant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiot%20savant), perhaps?

> **idiot sa·vant** (*n*.)
>   1. a person affected with a mental disability (as autism or mental retardation) who exhibits exceptional skill or brilliance in some limited field (as mathematics or music)
>   2. a person who is highly knowledgeable about one subject but knows little about anything else

Comment: That's still two words ;)

Comment: @Alain: it's not the worst fit, and you can easily drop the *idiot* part and just say [*savant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savant_syndrome).

Comment: I don't think that this meets the OP's requirements at all, as an idiot savant is a person who is actually *mentally retarded*, but has exaggerated ability in some narrow specialty. That's a very different thing from someone who has normal intelligence but a lack of practical common sense.

Comment: @JSBangs It is not always used in a technical sense; in fact, the technical sense doesn't exist anymore.  The second definition given above suffices for the OP's purposes.

Comment: *Idiot savant* is just like the words **moron**, **imbecile**, **idiot**, in that regard; they used to designate very precise IQ levels, but have become generalist terms to mean "stupid".

Comment: The term `savant` is commonly used now.  Actually, I had thought `idiot savant` was now considered offensive. In casual usage, I would assume a person described as a savant was particularly brilliant in some regard but generally foolish in most other areas.

Comment: No, watch a program on idiot savants. They usually have _astounding_ capability (to read extremely fast or solve multiplication problems in their head), but cannot form a sentence.

Answer (score 6):

You might be looking for *sophomore*, which (according to some sources) can be traced to the Greek words *sophos*, meaning "wise", and *moros*, meaning "fool".

Comment: Etymology rarely has anything to do with current usage. The adjective form *sophomoric* does have a disparaging meaning, but it means something akin to *immature*, with no cleverness implied. The noun *sophomore* doesn't even carry that meaning; it simply means a not-quite-beginner student.

Answer (score 4):

Such people could be said to live in an Ivory Tower

> **ivory tower** (*plural ivory towers*)
>   (*idiomatic*)
>
> A sheltered,
>   overly-academic existence or
>   perspective, implying a disconnection
>   or lack of awareness of reality or
>   practical considerations.
>
> *Such a
>   proposal looks fine from an ivory
>   tower, but it could never work in real
>   life.*

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ivory_tower

Comment: OP asked for an adjective that would describe a person, not a place where they can live.

Answer (score 4):

> What do you call a person who despite
>   being very clever in one field, e.g.
>   math or physics, behaves very unwisely
>   or impractical in real life?

Normal.

How many people fall for 'buy-one-get-one-free' offers (why isn't the price simply reduced) or 'super-size' deals?

I remember an old saying 'penny-wise, pound-foolish'

With tongue, embedded in cheek,

Chris

Comment: Actually, I think "Normal" - although most people wouldn't 'get it', is bang on. My observation has been that the smartest people I've known invariable have an equal-and-opposite (as it were) area of in-expertise.

Comment: The OP is looking for a word to describe people who are abnormally normal.

Answer (score 2):

Morosoph (n.) : A Learned fool.

Definition from Merriam Webster.

Comment: This is what [I would say](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/533510/365490)!

Answer (score 1):

The word *hubris* comes to mind; you wouldn't apply it to an individual but to his/her actions. Also, it has a connotation of arrogance rather than inadvertent behaviour; I am not sure this is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I would describe that type of person as having a 'lack of common sense' but I can't think of a single word to express the concept.

Comment: Read again. The OP tagged this under 'single-word-requests'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an *intellectual* would cover it, although this word more usually means experts in politics or economics who are likewise clueless about everyday reality.

Answer (score 1):

*Unworldly* or *otherworldly* are the best single words I can come up with.  There's no strong implication of expertise in a narrow field as there would be with *idiot savant* though.

Answer (score 1):

*Egghead* has a touch of both the positive and negative connotations you’re looking for. Maybe not enough. *Dreamer*, *daydreamer* and *visionary* are along the same lines.

The [*absent-minded professor* stereotype](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AbsentMindedProfessor) you describe is more or less what people conjure up when you say *philosopher*—though of course that word denotes a particular job or field of study.

Such a person is usually *eccentric* too.

Answer (score 0):

*Autistic* could be a word I would use in such cases, but I would mean it figuratively.

Comment: Perhaps if this were the 1950s... Even figuratively, that is fairly harsh given what we know today about the condition/spectrum.

Comment: @Michael Easter: The OP didn't ask for a word that would not be harsh.

Comment: Although autistic people are sometimes incredibly smart that is not always the case, and viceversa. In that sense Billare answer (*idiot savant*) is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're talking about [Professor Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Calculus).

Answer (score 0):

Literally, there's *sophomore* -  σοφός (sophos, “wise”) + μωρός (mōros, “fool”).