# Someone who comes across as "airheaded" but is really quite the opposite

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone who comes across as "airheaded" but is really quite the opposite?

I will add that the person is not deliberately trying to act stupid, they just come across that way when they speak. Without knowing them, you would assume this person holds no intellect.

Comment: [She's Crafty](http://www.metrolyrics.com/shes-crafty-lyrics-beastie-boys.html).

Comment: @Callithumpian I don't think OP specified a gender.

Comment: OP hasn't specified a lot of things: gender, whether or not this is part of an act, or even what is meant by "airheaded." Does that mean forgetful? Not very smart? Dresses with mismatching socks?

Comment: How about an example of a person or a character who seems air-headed but is actually a genius?

Comment: @coleopterist: Two former co-workers of mine spring to mind, as well as two of my mom's uncles, but, unfortunately, space won't allow me to elaborate and do those four men justice. As for somebody more famous, I might offer actress and musician Zooey Deschanel as a candidate. Or were you merely suggesting a rephrasing of the question?

Comment: @J.R. Yep, I was asking the OP to elaborate. I think that it would help to know what non-airheaded implies or if the airheadedness is being faked, etc. I was thinking of Goldie Hawn myself :)

Comment: As posted this question needs clarification. Unless it is improved, and I think this can be done only by the OP, then I will vote to close.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/is-there-a-word-for-clever-fool

Answer (score 4):

You could say that person is *understated* or *not obvious*. Phrases would include *easy to underestimate*, *easily undervalued*, *flies under the radar* or even "There's more to her than meets the eye."

Comment: Understated seems a good fit.

Comment: I'd argue, understated suggest *subtlety*, whereas the OP seems to be suggesting a *deceptive* appearance. The subject in question does not come across an understated way, but in a completely different way.

Comment: @CJM: Interesting how you and JAM (see JAM's comment to Eric's answer) are interpreting the O.P.'s question in opposite ways. (To me, that suggests it's time for the O.P. to elaborate.)

Comment: @Robusto - why the feminine? Just curious.

Comment: @JAM: Why not? It's an example instance. I could have said *John*, or *Sue*, or *physics*, or *armadillos* and you wouldn't have tried to edit it.

Comment: @Robusto just that a number of respondents assumed a feminine object, and none assumed a masculine. This is hardly the "generic feminine"! BTW lifting your "more than meets the eye" (in my answer) was an honest mistake - I hadn't noticed it in your answer when I made mine.

Comment: @J.R. - Perhaps I've not been clear - I largely agree with JAM's answer (and Elendil's) - they both votes from me. I disagree with Robusto's *understated*; this suggests the direction is right but the magnitude is wrong - but I think the OP means that the magnitude is perhaps equal, but the direction is completely wrong. I hope this vector analogy makes sense! Agree - let the OP wade it...

Comment: @CJM: I'm with you. Of the answers proposed so far, I can support _understated, cunning, misleading,_ and _absent-minded professor_. I even like _scatterbrained_. However, I pretty much have to redefine my interpretation of the question for each of these concur votes. :^)

Comment: @JAM: Just saw your "none assumed a masculine" comment. Although the answers here do reveal an apparent slant toward associating the word "airhead" with a woman, I'd like to point out that I mentioned two uncles and two former coworkers who happened to be named Larry and Steve. (Still, I'll confess, Amy was the very first airhead that sprung to mind.)

Comment: @J.R. - I did notice your comment! :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find a single word to fit the bill. You might say the person 'appeared deceptively airheaded'.

Another possibility is '[the person's] looks belie his/her intelligence'.

Answer (score 1):

The term *absent-minded professor* may address your concept. It is defined by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absent-minded_professor) (a questionable authority) as

> a talented academic whose focus on academic matters leads them to ignore or forget their surroundings.

It is often used to refer to someone who may be brilliant in some things, but gives an appearance of being scatterbrained.

Another term that is related is *idiot savant*. [American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/idiot%20savant) defines it as

> An intellectually disabled person who exhibits extraordinary ability in a highly specialized area, such as mathematics or music.

This literally refers to someone who *is* actually very limited but has a single high level of skill.  It is sometimes used colloquially to refer to someone who is smart but is acting like an *idiot*.

(It should be moted that the term *idiot*, along with other archaic terms for developmental disabilities, such as moron and imbecile, are often considered pejorative and offensive in US English.)

Answer (score 1):

You could say of such a person that there's ["more than meets the eye."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/more+than+meets+the+eye?s=t)

You could also say that the person's "appearance is deceiving."

Answer (score -1):

- *Misleading*;
- *Confusing*;
- If used in a sentence you could say "unexpectedly quiet".

Comment: Hi EM-Creations, and welcome to English.SE. I'm afraid that I don't think any of those convey the meaning requested in the question.

Comment: I feel they do, misleading certainly.

Comment: Yes, if you described a person as being _misleading_, it could indeed include the behaviour described above -- but it could also apply to many other behaviours. It's a little vague; most of the other answers here are a lot more specific.

Comment: It is vague, I agree but it's not incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

*Vulpine, foxy* or *cunning* may help you out. They hint at a deceptive cleverness.

Comment: These terms suggest that the person is *deliberately* misleading, and this does not appear to be the OP's intention.

Comment: @JAM: I'd like the O.P. to weigh in on that. I've known different people who played this one way or the other - some came across as airheads naturally and inadvertently, even though they were actually rather brilliant in spite of themselves, and I've also known people who often came off as airheads, but only as part of a ruse. (It's worth noting, perhaps, that I wouldn't label those in the latter category as _cunning_; they were more like _comedians_.)

Comment: *coughs, gives look*